# android Sqlite IllegalStateException on AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

Good day everyone.

So, I have an AsyncTask that calculates a Gaussian Blur from an image. The original image data is retrieved from SQLite using Blob field, also the filtered image is stored in SQLite. Here's the code (setQuizData is the function that does this):

```java
public class SaveFilterTask  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

private Context mContext;
private Context mApplicationContext;
private Quiz mQuiz;     

public SaveFilterTask(Context context, Quiz quiz, Context applicationContext) {
    super();
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mApplicationContext = applicationContext;
    this.mQuiz = quiz;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    try {
        setQuizData(mQuiz);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        cancel(true);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.error_loading_quiz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    if(!((Activity)mContext).isFinishing()){
        ((MainActivity)mContext).showDialog();
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

    if(!((Activity)mContext).isFinishing()){
        ((MainActivity)mContext).hideDialog();
    }

    Intent solveQuizIntent = new Intent(mContext, SolveQuizActivity.class);
    solveQuizIntent.putExtra(
            QuizConstants.KEY_PARCELABLE_FINISHED_QUIZ, mQuiz);
    solveQuizIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(solveQuizIntent);
}

private void setQuizData(Quiz quiz) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if(quiz.getType().equals(QuizConstants.TYPE_PHOTO)){
        QuizDataSource quizdatasource = new QuizDataSource(mApplicationContext);
        quizdatasource.open();
        String data = quizdatasource.getData(quiz.getId());
        quizdatasource.close();
        QuizDataSource quizdatasource2 = new QuizDataSource(mApplicationContext);
        quizdatasource2.open();
        String filterData = quizdatasource2.getDataFilter(quiz.getId());
        quizdatasource2.close();

        String filter = quiz.getFilter();
        if(filter != null){
            if(!filter.equals(QuizConstants.FILTER_DEFAULT)){
                Bitmap original = decodeImage(data);                                    
                if(filterData == null){         
                    data = FilterManager.applyFilter(original, quiz.getFilter());
                    Log.d("FilterManager","Data: "+ data);
                    Log.d("FilterManager","Id: "+ quiz.getId());
                    QuizDataSource quizdatasourceW = new QuizDataSource(mApplicationContext);
                    quizdatasourceW.open();
                    quizdatasourceW.setDataFilter(quiz.getId(), data);
                    quizdatasourceW.close();
                }                   
            }
        }           
    }
}


private static Bitmap decodeImage(String data) {         
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);                 
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
}

}
```

This task is called from my Activity, like this:

```java
SaveFilterTask sftask = new SaveFilterTask(this, quiz, getApplicationContext());
sftask.execute();
```

I don't know why sometimes (and randomly) I get this error:

```java
0java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
1at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
2at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
3at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
4at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
5at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
6at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
7at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
8at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
9Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/Data.db
10at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
11at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1156)
12at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
13at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
14at QuizDataSource.getDataFilter(QuizDataSource.java:119)
15at SaveFilterTask.setQuizData(SaveFilterTask.java:82)
16at SaveFilterTask.doInBackground(SaveFilterTask.java:39)
17at SaveFilterTask.doInBackground(SaveFilterTask.java:1)
```

I tried in different ways, using a single connection, using one connection for the read operations and one for the write operation. But the bug persists...

Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you shouldnt reinitialize QuazDataSource everytime.

Initialize it in the Construcotr and check it by using

```
if (quizdatasource  == null) {
    quizdatasource = CreateaQuizDataSourceHelper().open;
}
```

Then you should always make sure to close it, even when it fails.

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
  if (quizdatasource  == null) {
 quizdatasource = CreateaQuizDataSourceHelper().open;
  } 
  cursor= quizdatasource.rawQuery(...);
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
finally {
  if (quizdatasource != null) { quizdatasource.close(); }
}
```

at least make sure that your cursors are closed aswell by putting the validating in the finally block.

```
if (cursor != null) { cursor.close; }
```

then you shouldnt get multiple instances.

You should also create a SINGLETON Instance of your database, to make sure it's accessed only onec.

The Helper itself may have such a open method to make sure it's using the same connection.

```
    public SQLiteDatabase open() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;
    try {

        try {
            sqLiteDatabase = this.getDatabaseConnection();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            DataBaseConnectionPool.DbHelper DbHelper = this.dbHelper;
            if (DbHelper != null) {
                return this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sqLiteDatabase;
}
```